# how to export database table in 3 tabs for excel php

Tags: php, mysqli, export-to-excel

I have a button on my page that exports a table from the database to excel in three groups.  Works perfectly fine. What I want to do is for each group to be exported into a separate tab.

Here is my code:
    //export

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=feis_history.csv');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');

$output = fopen("php://output", "w"); 

//GRADES
fputcsv($output, array('GRADES'));
fputcsv($output, array('First Name', 'Competition Level', 'Competition Name', 'Date', 'Dance Name', 'Competition Number','Number of Competitors', 'Dancer`s Placement', 'Dancer`s Score', 'judge 1 comments', 'notes'));  

$sql = "SELECT `dancer_name`, `competition_level1`, `feis_entered`, `date`, `dance_name1`, `competition_number1`, `number_competitors1`, `dancer_placement1`, `dancer_score1`, `judge_comment1`, `notes`  FROM `mark_cards1` WHERE user_id = '$id' AND grades = 'yes' ORDER BY YEAR(date) ASC, dancer_name, feis_entered";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    fputcsv($output, $row );  
}

//CHAMPION
fputcsv($output, array('CHAMPION'));
fputcsv($output, array('First Name', 'Competition Level', 'Competition Name', 'Date', 'Dance Name', 'Competition Number','Number of Competitors', 'Dancer`s Placement', 'Was Recalled?', 'Recalled Dancers', 'Dancer`s Score', 'judge 1 comments', 'judge 2 comments', 'judge 3 comments', 'notes'));  

$sql = "SELECT `dancer_name`, `competition_level1`, `feis_entered`, `date`, `dance_name1`, `competition_number1`, `number_competitors1`, `dancer_placement1`, `was_recalled`, `recall1`, `dancer_score1`, `judge_comment1`, `judge_comment2`, `judge_comment3`, `notes`  FROM `mark_cards1` WHERE user_id = '$id' AND champion = 'yes' ORDER BY YEAR(date) ASC, dancer_name, feis_entered";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    fputcsv($output, $row );  
}

//MAJOR
fputcsv($output, array('MAJOR'));
fputcsv($output, array('First Name', 'Competition Level', 'Competition Name', 'Date', 'Dance Name', 'Competition Number','Number of Competitors', 'Dancer`s Placement', 'Was Recalled?', 'Recalled Dancers', 'Dancer`s Score', 'judge 1 Score', 'judge 2 Score', 'judge 3 Score', 'judge 4 Score', 'judge 5 Score', 'notes'));  

$sql = "SELECT `dancer_name`, `competition_level1`, `feis_entered`, `date`, `dance_name1`, `competition_number1`, `number_competitors1`, `dancer_placement1`, `was_recalled`, `recall1`, `dancer_score1`, `judge1_score`, `judge2_score`, `judge3_score`, `judge4_score`, `judge5_score`, `notes`  FROM `mark_cards1` WHERE user_id = '$id' ORDER BY YEAR(date) ASC, dancer_name, feis_entered";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    fputcsv($output, $row;  
}

  fclose($output);  
?>
```

So what I want is for Grades to be in a tab called grades, Champion in a tab called Champion, and Major in a tab called Major.

Comment: Since you are creating simple CSV files you aren't going to be able to create tabs. CSV files aren't "true" Excel files and aren't able to contain features like separate sheets/tabs. You may find that the [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) provides a way to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

CSV (**C**omma-**S**eparated **V**alues) files do not contain "tabs" as you see in Excel:

This is what an CSV file looks like:

```
id,name,active
1,jack,0
2,peter,1
3,luke,1
```

This is a text file with individual items separated by commas (`,`) and new entries in new lines.

There's no fancy tabs. The solution could be for you to have separate files for each item, then, individually save them into their dedicated files (grades.csv, champion.csv, etc).

Or as it was suggested use a dedicated library to manage office files, those would be the two best solutions.